# TypeScript: How to convert type properties to class members

Tags: typescript, class, types

I got this type:

```
type User = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

On the other hand, I got abstract class which can be extended and passed some fields. If I want to have User properties as fields in this class, I need to pass every separate field, like so:

```
abstract class UserModel {
  name: User['name'];
  email: User['email'];
  password: User['password'];
}
```

Which is of course very inconvenient given that I have to repeat all the information that I have in other place.

Is there any way to do this automatically, using some specific syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you want an abstract class here?

**Solution one: no abstract class**

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

class Bob implements User {
  email = 'bob@bobson.com';
  name = 'Bob';
  password = 'bobson666';
}
```

**Solution two: with abstract class**

You can use an interface to define your properties and implement the class next to it:

```
interface UserModel {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

abstract class UserModel {
  name = 'Bob'; // Correct
  name = 42; // Error: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'name' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number'.(2717)
}
```

Having a `class` and and `interface` in the same scope makes TypeScript merge their definitions, so you don't need to repeat yourself while still maintaining type safety when assigning the properties.